# How to retrieve data from phpmyadmin databse using yii

Tags: php, database, yii, data-retrieval

Good day .. I am having a problem here to retrieve data from certain column in db using yii framework.. I am a complete newbie to yii, but still managing,

I read lot of posts, forums and YouTube but none are working for me to get data from db as I want it, any help is much appreciated!

When it comes to authenticating users, its perfect. But when normally trying to retrieve other data than user authentication. I keep getting `Error 500
Trying to get property of non-object` and stuff.

So using the authentication method in SiteControler, I took advantage in the `$model` .. and re used it for my purpose:

```
 $user = $model->username;
```

here username is perfectly giving me the value of username logged in.

But when I try to point from username to check another column in the same row called "UserAuth". It doesn't work!

I think logically, it should be like this:

```
 $model->username->UserAuth;
```

Am I right? even when I add `$this->UserAuth` its still the same!!

The column I want to check is called "UserAuth" in my table called "logins"..
So matching the username, was successful, but the same method I used didn't work for checking other column. Hope I gave a clear pic here.

I am using yii 1 not 2, if that help (don't know the difference through)

Again to point that, I am new to web development era .. I used to do basic java SE .. but web seems different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried

```
$model->username->UserAuth;
```

and

```
$this->UserAuth
```

But what you need to do is:

```
$model->UserAuth;
```

The `$model` represents a row in the database. Each column is accessed as a separate property.

```
$model->username;
$model->UserAuth;
$model->anotherColumn;
$model->yetAnotherColumn;
```

This, of course, assumes that `$model` is an object whose class extends `CActiveRecord`. Without seeing more of your code, I can't be sure that it is or not.

Comment: oh i see, this perspective never came to my mind..Thanks for the tip mate :D